# MySql: Get both tables record without using union

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

`team` has the following fields. User can create a team.

```
id
title
```

`team_users` has the following fields. `team_users` will contain all users who are assigned for the team.

```
id
team_id
user_id
role - leader, student
```

`classes` has the following fields. User can create a classes.

```
id
team_id
class_name
user_id
```

Data goes like below

```
`team`
id| title
1 | New team
2 | Other team

`team_users`
id | team_id | user_id | role
1  |    1    |   1     | leader
2  |    2    |   3     | student

classes
 id | team_id | class_name | creator_id
 1  |   1     | Other class|   2
 2  |   2     | My class   |   1
```

Now I want to list all classes which a user has created and also those classes of his assigned team he is as a leader which he doesn't create.

The result should be both classes if I want all sessions of a user whose id is 1. because 1 has created "My class" class and 1 is part of the team which has an "Other Class" class.

It is possible to get records without a union?

Comment: So a leader can create(creator_id) a class even though he is not a member of the team(team_id) in classes? But a student cannot? Also please add your expected output.

Comment: I can create a team and i can directly create a class. other user can assign me a leader of their team.

Comment: But in your example user_id 1 is not a member of team 2.

Comment: yes. because I can create a team and assign a uses so I did not enter team creator id inside team_user table

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need a join with an ON..OR and a group_concat

```
drop table if exists team,team_users,classes;

create table `team`
(id int, title varchar(10));
insert into team values
(1 , 'New team'),
(2 , 'Other team');

create table `team_users`
(id int, team_id int, user_id int, role varchar(10));
insert into team_users values
(1  ,    1    ,   1     , 'leader'),
(2  ,    2    ,   3     , 'student');

create table classes
( id int, team_id int, class_name varchar(20), creator_id int);
insert into classes values
( 1  ,   1     , 'Other class' ,   2),
( 2  ,   2     , 'half baked'  ,   1),
( 2  ,   2     , 'My class'    ,   1);

 select user_id , 
        group_concat(c.class_name)  classes
 from team_users tu
 left join classes c on c.creator_id = tu.user_id or c.team_id = tu.team_id
 where tu.user_id = 1;

+---------+---------------------------------+
| user_id | classes                         |
+---------+---------------------------------+
|       1 | Other class,half baked,My class |
+---------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```